# Disconnect after X minutes inactivity?

Tags: configuration, help, linux, circuit, attacks

I read somewhere its not a good idea to remain connected to TOR network for long periods of time because it gives an attackers more opportunity to de-anonymize.

The machine I am using is unatttended much of the time, and would otherwise be 'always on', the TOR network which worries me.

Is there a way to make TOR check for network inactivity and disconnect automatically after X minutes?

If so, is there a quick simple way to reconnect after disconnect?

Ideal scenario would be for it to sense a proxied web browser being used on it again and arc back up, but dont know if this is possible.

Can it detect browser activity and connect?

Thankyou TOR gurus

Comment: Where did you hear this from? People make a lot of claims about the Tor Network, but many of them aren't true. If you are concerned about this, you can simply click the "New Identity" button (the spaceship button) to force the browser to use new circuits.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?